# Select2 no funciona dentro del modal

Tags: laravel, modal, select2, livewire, laravel-jetstream

Al momento de ejecutar el modal el select2 no funciona simplemente queda como select comun, probe el select2 afuera del modal y si funciona correctamente. para el modal estoy utilizando componente de jetsteam

select2 dentro del modal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

select2 afuera del modal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Page modal

```
<div>
    <x-button-blue wire:click="$set('open',true)">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-user-plus"></i> &nbsp;&nbsp;AGREGAR DEPARTAMENTO
    </x-button-blue>

    <x-jet-dialog-modal wire:model="open">
        
        <x-slot name="title">Agregar Usuario</x-slot>
        
        <x-slot name="content">
            <div class="mb-4">
                <x-jet-label value="Departamento" />
                <x-jet-input type="text" wire:model.defer="departamento" />
                <x-jet-input-error for="departamento" />
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Minimal</label>
                <select class="form-control select2" style="width: 100%;">
                  <option selected="selected">Alabama</option>
                  <option>Alaska</option>
                  <option>California</option>
                  <option>Delaware</option>
                  <option>Tennessee</option>
                  <option>Texas</option>
                  <option>Washington</option>
                </select>
              </div>


        </x-slot>
        
        <x-slot name="footer">
            <x-jet-secondary-button wire:click="$set('open',false)">Cancelar</x-jet-secondary-button>
            <x-jet-danger-button wire:click="save">Confirmar</x-jet-danger-button>
        </x-slot>

    </x-jet-dialog-modal>

</div>
```

Page view

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

eh estado buscando y me tope que no era el único y las soluciones que daban no me funcionaron asd

Comment: No se cuando defines el modal, seguramente después de la carga inicial del documento de forma dinámica, por lo tanto debes volver a ejecutar la carga en javascript del select2 cuando eso ocurra

Comment: Y por favor, no uses imágenes para poner código pues recibirás peores ayudas al no poder reproducir tu escenario de forma cómoda. Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta agregándolo como texto y haciendo las modificaciones que necesites tantas veces como quieras.

Answer (score 0):

```
@push('script')
    <script>
      $('.selectpicker').select2();
    </script>
@endpush
```

debes colocar el fragmento de arriba en tu componente,y app.blade.php  declara  lo siguiente `@stack('script')`

Comment: ¿Puedes editar la respuesta explicando cómo esos pasos solucionan el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Use:
dropdownParent

Ejemplo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select2insidemodal").select2({
    dropdownParent: $("#myModal")
  });
});
```

Dejo una respuesta referente a la consulta aquí por si alguien llegue a necesitar.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18487056/select2-doesnt-work-when-embedded-in-a-bootstrap-modal

Comment: Si bien este enlace puede responder a la pregunta, es mejor incluir las partes esenciales de la respuesta aquí y proporcionar el enlace como referencia.  Las respuestas que son únicamente un enlace pueden dejar de ser válidas si la página vinculada cambia. - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/384988)

Comment: Hola Thania, gracias por colaborar, la respuesta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edítala, elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos y lograrás que sea mejor recibida, gracias. .